# Detect a keyword entered in a textarea when user clicks submit on a form

Tags: jquery, textarea

using jQuery, is it possible to detect if a keyword (or multiple keywords) has been entered in a textarea when a user clicks submit on a form?

Say I type, "This text has a keyword in it." and click submit in the form, is it possible to display a simple alert that tells me that I typed this particular word?

Thanks for any info you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's easy

```
var text = $('textarea#mytextarea').val(); //gets the text from textarea user your own id
if (text.indexOf("keyword") >= 0)
  alert('keyword');
```

**EDIT:**
you have to put this code to be triggered by the submit button. if this is your form

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
<input type="text" value="Hello there" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

then you can trigger it by doing this

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  var text = $('textarea#mytextarea').val(); //gets the text from textarea user your own id
  if (text.indexOf("keyword") >= 0)
    alert('keyword');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Add a $('#your_form').submit(function() {}) arround!

Comment: And get rid of the semi-colon after the `if` statement.

Comment: @powtac was actualy doing that

Comment: Excellent, Thank you! EDIT: Didn't see the other guys comments, I'd already fixed it up, thanks anyway.