# How to set a specific keyword/password sent through textarea that trigger JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, passwords, textarea, keyword

That's my first ever question, and it's about my very first project, it's an online RPG Forum/PlayByChat game. I know it's kinda of an ambitious project.

So, i'm stuck from months into a problem that i feel i'm close to solve, premise (I'm self-taught).

The idea is to activate an if statement by a keyword/password given by an NPC, if there isn't no keyword in the message that it's supposed to be sent, then nothing should to happen.

That's what i've been able to put together and modify a little bit (it's not the entire code, just the interested parts), it works but it gets activated by any words or even by just one letter/empty messagges, i recently added the attribute "required" to the textarea so the field needs to be fill before to send messagges (even though it works only for the first click, then gives the possibility to send empty messagges which of course triggers the JoinedInTheRoom function) but anyway, that's a minor problem, the main problem remains that i cannot figured out how to make work the if statement inside the event listener under the JoinedInTheRoom function with a pre-chosen keyword/password, let's say "Mellon" (not case-sensitive if possible).

i'll explain myself better.

Let's say i'm gonna write "Mellon fellas" in the TextArea inside the Chat Log, my idea is to simply trigger the JoinedInTheRoom function by the fact that "Mellon", the keyword, has been just sent inside the messagge, i hope that my intent it's clear.

Thanks in advance.

here is the code:

**HTML - CHAT LOG + TEXT AREA AND BUTTON**

```
<!-- CHAT LOG -->
<h3>Chat Log</h3>
<div class="ChatLog">

  <div class="msg left-msg">
    <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url()"></div>
    <div class="msg-bubble">
      <div class="msg-info">
        <div class="msg-info-name">System</div>
      </div>
      <div class="msg-text">Write the Keyword to join the room and unlock the NPCs and Quests</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- TEXT AREA AND BUTTON -->
<form class="FormInputArea">
  <textarea class="InputCamp" id="TextArea" placeholder="Explain your move in max 200 characters..." required></textarea>
  <button class="button" type="submit" id="SendButton"> Send </button>
</form>
```

**JAVA SCRIPT - CHAT LOG + TEXT AREA AND BUTTON**

```
// CHAT LOG + TEXT AREA AND BUTTON

const ChatLog = get(".ChatLog");
const FormInputArea = get(".FormInputArea");
const InputCamp = get(".InputCamp");
```

**JAVA SCRIPT - JoinedInTheRoom + NpcsUnlocked**

```
// JoinedInTheRoom + NpcsUnlocked

function JoinedInTheRoom(side) {

const NpcsUnlocked = `
  <div class="msg ${side}-msg">
    <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(${BOT_IMG})"></div>

    <div class="msg-bubble">
      <div class="msg-info">
        <div class="msg-info-name">${BOT_NAME}</div>
        <div class="msg-info-time">${formatDate(new Date())}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="msg-text">You've joined the room, feel free to choose your quest.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="msg ${side}-msg">
    <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(${BOT_IMG})"></div>

    <div class="msg-bubble">
      <div class="msg-info">
        <div class="msg-info-name">${BOT_NAME}</div>
        <div class="msg-info-time">${formatDate(new Date())}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="msg-text">
        <p onclick="Npc1('RANDOM TASK DESCRIPTION 1')"> Npc 1. </p>
        <p onclick="Npc2('RANDOM TASK DESCRIPTION 2')"> Npc 2. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `;

  ChatLog.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", NpcsUnlocked);
    ChatLog.scrollTop += 500;
}
  FormInputArea.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const NpcsUnlocked = InputCamp.value;
  if (!NpcsUnlocked) return;

  const Delay = NpcsUnlocked.split(" ").length * 600;

  setTimeout(() => {
    JoinedInTheRoom("left", NpcsUnlocked);
    InputCamp.value = " ";
  }, Delay);
})
```

**JAVA SCRIPT - PLAYER MESSAGE SCRIPT**

```
// PLAYER MESSAGE SCRIPT

function AppendMessage(name, img, side, text) {

  const msgHTML = `
    <div class="msg ${side}-msg">
      <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(${img})"></div>

      <div class="msg-bubble">
        <div class="msg-info">
          <div class="msg-info-name">${name}</div>
          <div class="msg-info-time">${formatDate(new Date())}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="msg-text">${text}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  ChatLog.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", msgHTML);
    ChatLog.scrollTop += 500;
}
  FormInputArea.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const msgText = InputCamp.value;
  if (!msgText) return;

  AppendMessage(PERSON_NAME, PERSON_IMG, "right", msgText);
  InputCamp.value = "";
});
```

Searching on internet i found this 11 years old stackoverflow post that i think it might help me, it seems i might use "indexOf" for this job, i'm right ? Maybe you guys can help me make it a little bit more "modern" and apply it to my code ?

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039205/detect-a-keyword-entered-in-a-textarea-when-user-clicks-submit-on-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .includes function, like below

```
if (msgText.includes("mellon")) {
    JoinedInTheRoom();
}
```

It'll search the whole string and return true if "mellon" is found. However it will also return true if someone types a word containing mellon. "smellon" or "smellonies" would return true and run the JoinedInTheRoom function too

Comment: Hello ! Sound really interesting, surely it would be a step foward to my goal. There isn't a way to shrink the options to only the specified word ? To avoid the possibilties to activate the function with words that aren't the true keyword.